# Trying to create nested view of django model classes using relations

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to follow this documentation to create nested serializer and api view. 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

However, I am not able to understand what did I miss as my results are not expected.

I have followed this example to my case and checked various other guides regarding same. Tried different views and different serializer formats.

Code for model is this:-

```
class Round(models.Model):
    player_num = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)

class Seats(models.Model):
    stack = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    round = models.ForeignKey(Round, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=STATE)
```

code for Serializers is this:-

```
class SeatsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Seats
        fields = ('stack','state')

class RoundSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    seats = SeatsSerializer(many = True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Round
        fields = ('player_num','seats')
```

I want output like this:

```
{
  'player_num': 3,
  'seats': [
    {'stack': 100, 'state': 'participating', 'name': 'p1', 'uuid': 'ftwdqkystzsqwjrzvludgi'},
    {'stack': 100, 'state': 'participating', 'name': 'p2', 'uuid': 'bbiuvgalrglojvmgggydyt'},
  ]
}
```

However, output I get is:

```
{
  'player_num': 3,
}
```

Comment: There needs to be a [relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) between the Seats and Round models if you want to use DRF nested serializers.

Comment: There is, I made a typo. I made the edit now. Please check

Comment: Try replacing `seats` with `seats_set` in `RoundSerializer` (2x).

Comment: Oh .. works!! Such lame error. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Consider using singular model names though (`Seat`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
round = models.ForeignKey(Round, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='seats')
```